# How to List clusters by subscription ID using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-subscription

New to Azure SDK for .NET, can someone help in providing on how to list all clusters in a subscription using subscription ID only. I am trying to bypass using Resource Group to save time.

Previously we could use ContainerServiceClient but the package Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerService has been deprecated and I couldn't find an appropriate example using latest package versions

Comment: Why not use Powershell.  Powershell is written in Net and has a lot of functions that work easily with Azure.

Comment: @jdweng The function I am trying to create is part of a larger codebase in .NET/C#, Powershell or Python is not possible here

Comment: It is an HTTP request with the parameters of the request following the question mark in the URI.  So in c# all you need to do is to send an HTTP Request and get the json response.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters/list?view=rest-aks-2023-08-01&tabs=HTTP

Comment: @jdweng Never mind found the solution! class Azure.ResourceManager.Resources.SubscriptionResource has inbuilt function GetContainerServiceManagedClusters() which provides all the data I need

Comment: @MuditBalooja Please post your solution as answer for the community

Answer (score 0):

I do agree @Mudit Balooja that using **`Azure.ResourceManager.Resources`** we can get clusters as below:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.ContainerService;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;


ArmClient rithwik_client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());

SubscriptionResource rithwik_subscription = await rithwik_client.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
Console.WriteLine(rithwik_subscription.GetContainerServiceManagedClusters());
```

**`Output:`**

[image]